# Integration over first Brillouin zone

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals, lattice-model

I have the following lattice and reciprocal lattice and Brillouin zone:

[image]

There is such integral $\frac{1}{V_{first~BZ}}\int_{first~BZ} f(k_1,k_2)dk_1dk_2$, where $k_1 = \vec{k} \cdot \hat{n}_1$ and $k_2 = \vec{k} \cdot \hat{n}_2$, where $\hat{n}_{1,2} = (\sqrt{3}/2,\pm 1/2)$.

My question is how to evaluate above integral. What is the integration range for $k_1$ and $k_2$? Should $V_{first~BZ}$ be the area of first Brillouin zone, which is $\frac{8\pi^2}{3\sqrt{3}a^2}$ according to my calculation? If $V_{first~BZ} = \frac{8\pi^2}{3\sqrt{3}a^2}$, shouldn't the integral with $f(k_1,k_2)=1$ gives you 1 for above integral?